# Deploying multiple SQL Server 2014 databases in one go

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dacpac

I have 5 .dacpac files, one dacpac for one database, with a SQL Server 2014 target. The very last database in the list has a dependency on the other 4.

I can deploy each .dacpac individually using sqlpackage.exe which works great.

What I'd really like to do, is do this "transactionally", if that's the correct word for this context, so that when I'm creating 5 databases, if any deployment goes wrong, all deployments roll back.

Either all databases are created, or none are.

Is this feasible, and if so, how could I do it? I'm not averse to Powershell scripting if it comes to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell can do that, although you will have to manually control the "transaction"

First create a powershell script that deploys the dacpacs - i.e. you should be able to copy and paste each sqpackage.exe command line with the desired parameters

Then wrap each command in a powershell try/catch block, each catch section will have to have the appropriate manual rollback commands to tidy things up at each stage.

Comment: Hi Jimbo, thanks for replying. Is it possible for me enlist 5 sqlpackage.exe deployments in a single Sql transaction?  Tried to find info on this w/ google, not had much joy...

Comment: No.  e.g. dacpac uses drop database - that command cannot be used in a t-sql transaction.